# xcode swift cell detailTextLabel.text?. color taken from date

Tags: xcode, swift, date, colors

i try to change the labelcolor, if the "date" in my detailTextLabel.text older then today..

```
        // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

    let item = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Item
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.name! + "-" + item.etage! + "-" + item.raum!
    let note = item.date
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "\(note!)"

    if note == "01.04.2016 23:00" {
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    } else {

    }

    return cell
}
```

How can i do this? It works with a specific date but not with NSDate() or something like this. I go crazy!

big thx!

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807416/check-if-date-is-before-current-date-swift  and make sure compare with same format

Comment: apparently  your Item.date is in String format so it's not possible to directly compare with an NSDate object.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35022615/3466461) you can make something like this:

```
...
let note = item.date
let now = NSDate()

if note.earlierDate(now).isEqualToDate(note)  {
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

Comment: thx =) but now i have a message:  Value of type 'String?' has no member 'earlierDate'

Comment: Try using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29319732/3466461) extension in your code